# NoClassDefFoundError while using docx4j in IBM message broker v8

Tags: java, docx4j, messagebroker

I have a requirement to create a word document. So I am trying to use docx4j. I get a runtime error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage
```

I am sure I have docx4j3.0.1 and all the dependencies added to my build path.

Is there an issue with the class initialization mechanism?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Had to add all the jars to the MQSI/shared-classes folder. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference a good way to resolve these problems on IBM JRE platforms is to set the environment variable IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dibm.cl.verbose=* and restart the Broker.

This will cause classloading trace to be written to Broker's standard output (located in $MQSI_WORKPATH/components//

This shows you what jars are available in each classloader and which classloaders are being searched whenever a class is loaded.